# Why is my resource_map function in R asking for a quasiquoted argument?

Tags: r

I am trying to run (in R) this off-the-shelf example from the Resource Map function help page:

```
    library(bupaR)
    library(eventdataR)
    data(patients)
    resource_map(patients)
```

and somehow it is returning this error:

> Error: `UQ()` can only be used within a quasiquoted argument

Can someone help me understand and propose a fix as well? Is it something with my R/Rstudio, because this example comes straight from the "resource_map" help page.

Here is the sessioninfo:

> R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
>   (64-bit) Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
>   LAPACK:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
>
> locale: [1]
>   en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] bindrcpp_0.2        xesreadR_0.2.2
>   processmonitR_0.1.0 processmapR_0.2.1   eventdataR_0.1.2
>   petrinetR_0.1.0     [7] edeaR_0.7.2         bupaR_0.3.2
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rook_1.1-1
>   purrr_0.2.4         ggthemes_3.4.0      colorspace_1.3-2
>   viridisLite_0.3.0   miniUI_0.1.1         [7] htmltools_0.3.6
>   yaml_2.1.17         plotly_4.7.1        XML_3.98-1.10
>   rlang_0.2.0         pillar_1.2.1        [13] glue_1.2.0
>   RColorBrewer_1.1-2  bindr_0.1           plyr_1.8.4
>   stringr_1.3.0       munsell_0.4.3       [19] gtable_0.2.0
>   visNetwork_2.0.3    htmlwidgets_1.0     forcats_0.3.0
>   httpuv_1.3.6.2      DiagrammeR_0.9.2    [25] Rcpp_0.12.15
>   xtable_1.8-2        readr_1.1.1         scales_0.5.0
>   jsonlite_1.5        rgexf_0.15.3        [31] mime_0.5
>   gridExtra_2.3       brew_1.0-6          ggplot2_2.2.1       hms_0.4.1 
>   digest_0.6.15       [37] stringi_1.1.6       dplyr_0.7.4
>   shiny_1.0.5         grid_3.4.3          influenceR_0.1.0
>   tools_3.4.3         [43] magrittr_1.5        lazyeval_0.2.1
>   tibble_1.4.2        tidyr_0.8.0         pkgconfig_2.0.1     xml2_1.2.0
>   [49] data.table_1.10.4-3 downloader_0.4      lubridate_1.7.3
>   httr_1.3.1          assertthat_0.2.0    rstudioapi_0.7      [55]
>   viridis_0.5.0       R6_2.2.2            igraph_1.1.2
>   shinyTime_0.2.1     compiler_3.4.3

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that all your packages are up to date.

Comment: everything is up to date: R/Rstudio/libraries

Comment: What does your `sessionInfo()` show after you load these libraries?

Comment: @MrFlick: I have updated the question adding the sessionInfo(). thanks.